# Why does a negative number subtracted from a variable move the graph of the function right? ie Why is the h in |x+h| move it the opposite of its sign?

Tags: absolute-value

Earlier in math class, I learned that you move an absolute value function right by subtracting from the variable inside the absolute value. For example, |x-1| is one unit to the right, not the left. Why is this?

Comment: You get the same values of $x-1$ as you would with $x$ when you plug in values one unit to the right. For example $\left. x-1 \right |_{x=1}=\left. x \right |_{x=0}$.

Comment: If $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=|x+1|$, then $g(x-1)=|x|$. In other words, to get the same $y$-value as before, you need to plug in an $x$-value that is *one unit smaller*.